# count check using pyspark from azure storage

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I have files in blob storage

```
abc_1.csv
abc_1.ok
def_2.csv
def_2.ok
ghi_3.csv
ghi_3.ok
```

where .csv contains data and .ok contains the data count i.e all csv have data and .ok have the file count of the individual csv.
The data in the .ok file is as

```
abc_1_2
def_2_12
gh1_3_56
```

where the 2,12,56 are the count of the files in the .csv files.

My requirement is to count the rows from csv files individually and then compare it with the respective .ok file where the count is mentioned at the last as stated in the above statement.

I am using the below code snippet but need some help more:

```
import fnmatch
import os
basepath = '/mnt/demo/fold1'
count1 = len(fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(basepath), '*.ok'))
print(count1)
count2 = len(fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(basepath), '*.csv'))
print(count2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read `*.csv` files into dataframe and `*.ok` into another dataframe. Get the count on each and then join on the filename.

Something like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df_csv = spark.read.csv("path/fold1/*.csv") \
    .withColumn("filename", F.input_file_name()) \
    .groupby("filename") \
    .agg(F.count("*").alias("count_csv"))

df_ok = spark.read.csv("path/fold1/*.ok").toDF("file_count") \
    .withColumn("filename", F.regexp_replace(F.input_file_name(), "\\.ok", ".csv")) \
    .select("filename", F.substring_index("file_count", "_", -1).alias("count_ok"))


df_compare = df_csv.join(df_ok, ["filename"])
df_compare.show()
```

Comment: i suppose here i will have to provide the file names indivisually however i have a requirement to have a loop where in it will keep considering the .csv files and .ok files and to record count check

Comment: df_csv = spark.read.csv("/dbfs/mnt/abc/20201111/*.csv") when i do so its throwing me an error stating path does not exits could you please help

Comment: @PradyotMohanty try with path `dbfs:/mnt/abc/20201111/*.csv`

Comment: the real format of data in the *.ok is abc_1_2 where till abc_1 is the file name same as the respective csv file name and the last part that is _2, or _12 or _56 is the total count of the records in the actual csv file i.e abc_1.csv,def_2.csv

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228619/discussion-between-blackbishop-and-pradyot-mohanty).